# Speech recognition for python, raspberry pi

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi3, speech-to-text

This is a really big ask but I have tried for about 4 months now trying to get this to work. So, I am creating a personal assistant using a raspberry pi 3 model B and python (I know they are not the best of choices). Most of it works apart from the main feature, the speech to text (STT). I would like it to convert all spoken words to text and when you finish a sentence I would like it to enter and finish so the text can be processed as a string. Do you have any suggestions on what I could use to do this or any links to help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have completed similar project to yours recently.
If internet connection is not a problem for you, I would suggest using [Wit.ai](https://wit.ai/). It has nice [Python API](https://github.com/wit-ai/pywit), or you could use it through [HTTP API](https://wit.ai/docs/http/20170307).

Your assistant would have to record speech, then send data to remote API and receive response with text as an answer.

Take into account, that STT process is quite complex, so trying to solve it with local solutions might be a bit too much to cope with for Raspberry. What's more, you would have to (probably) prepare vocabularies, etc. Using remote STT service, you don't have to do that.

If you cannot, or do not want to use remote service, you can always try CMU Sphinx. But for that, you need somebody else to help you with it, as I have no experience using it whatsoever.